# How to update model with new records in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a table that gets populated based on records from a rest API. All of this works fine.

Now I want to add some buttons on top of the table. When these buttons are clicked, the api is called again but this time with some parameters. Then I want the table to be updated with these new records. How can I achieve this?

My template looks like this:

```
<div id="myEmberElement">
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="posts">
        <div id="controls">
           <a href="#" id="mostrated">MostRated</a>
           <a href="#" id="mostsold">MostSold</a>
        </div>

        <table>
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>author</th>
            <th>book</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {{#each model}}
            <tr>
              <td>{{author}}</td>
              <td>{{book}}</td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </script>
 </div>
```

and my App.js is this:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.rootElement = "#myEmberElement";

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("posts");
});

App.Request = DS.Model.extend({
    author: DS.attr("string"),
    book: DS.attr("string")
});

App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return App.Request.find();
    }
});
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo("posts");
    }
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
        url: '/myapp'
    })
});
```

**What I've Tried**

I stuck the following in my App.js but that did not help:

```
$("#mostrated").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('came here');
    App.Request.find({filter: "mostrated"})
});
```

Now when `mostrated` is clicked I can see that a new request is made to `myapp/requests?filter=mostrated` and data is also returned back from the server.

**Question**

Problem is that the table does not get repopulated with new data. It still has the old data. How can I force the `{{#each model}}` to populate the data again?? Sample of this app (with local data) is also on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/OcAyoYo/2/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The short:

http://jsbin.com/OcAyoYo/12/edit

### The long:

A possible approach to filter the content could be to define separate routes with their own model hooks setup, instead of using actions, this would result in the follow refactoring of your code:

**Template**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="posts">
  <div id="controls">
    {{#linkTo 'posts.all'}}All{{/linkTo}}
    {{#linkTo 'posts.mostRated'}}MostRated{{/linkTo}}
    {{#linkTo 'posts.mostSold'}}MostSold{{/linkTo}}
  </div>
  {{outlet}}
</script>
```

**Router map**

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("posts", function() {
    this.route("all");
    this.route("mostRated");
    this.route("mostSold");
  });
});
```

**Additional routes for the filtered content**

```
App.PostsMostRatedRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Response.find({filter: "mostrated"});
  }
});

App.PostsMostSoldRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Response.find({filter: "mostsold"});
  }
});
```

As you will see in the demo mentioned above the changes I've done in your ajax call are just to simulate a filtering since no server is involved in the example. I've also added a property in your sample JSON to have something to filter for, all this would be done by your server I guess so ignore this changes since they are not related to my proposed solution.

Hope it helps.

Comment: great! that works. Nested routes seems like a good approach. However, with nested routes I will need two templates `posts/mostsold` and `posts/mostrated` but they do the exacty same thing (build table and loop over model). Maybe I'm asking for too much now that this is working but is there a way to keep the template same? If I have 10 filters I don't want to have 10 templates doing the same thing...

Comment: @Anthony, sure, you could have `partial`'s let me try to tweak the jsbin to show what I mean

Comment: @Anthony, ok, check out the updated jsbin in the answer, would this be a viable solution for you?

Comment: @intuitevepixel I would also like to show a spinner while moving between the different templates. Is there something builtin for that?

Comment: @Anthony, indeed there is a `LoadingRoute` built-in, take a look at this updated http://jsbin.com/OcAyoYo/15/edit. also you can read here more: https://gist.github.com/machty/5647589 under *How do I put up a (global) Loading Spinner during a transition w/ Promises?*

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35957/discussion-between-anthony-and-intuitivepixel)