# How to filter data for rest API based on drop downs

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-data

I asked a similar question earlier for which I got a lot of help: [How to update model with new records in EmberJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365779/how-to-update-model-with-new-records-in-emberjs/18368079#18368079)

With that question I'm able to filter the data by making different templates for each filter item.

But I'd like to filter the data by selecting something from the drop down and then typing something in the text box. So if `starts` was selected from the drop down and `4` was entered in the text box and `submit` was clicked then the request would be made to `find({stars: "4"})`

**What I've done so far**

I created a new nested template `posts/dynamicfinder` When the submit button is clicked I'm getting the selected value from drop down and the text from the text box. At this point I want to `transitionToRoute dynamicfinder` along with the `filterterm` and `filtertype`.  How can I do this?

```
App.PostsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   content: [],
   filterterm: "",
   submit: function () {
       var filtertype =  App.names.selected;
       var filterterm =  this.get('filterterm');
       this.transitionToRoute("posts.dynamicfinder", App.Request.find({filtertype: filterterm})); 
       //the above line gives me errors
   }
});
```

Here is the jsBin for this: http://jsbin.com/OcAyoYo/33/edit